# Getting @Id's DataType from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, jpa

I'm writing a library that will be used to Hibernate many types of EJBs via JPA.  When loading an EJB from JPA, the library needs the datatype of the field(s) annotated with @Id.  The @Id may be annotated on a superclass of the EJB.  Is there a method in Hibernate or JPA that can get the datatype of @Id?

I'm tempted to use reflection, but this would require recursion and code that probably already exists in JPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can get to the Hibernate SessionFactory you can call `sf.getClassMetaData("Your.Class.Name").getIdentifierType().getReturnedClass()` (remember to null check that code ;)